# VBA code to iterate through a dropdown list and then copy/paste a range for each iteration into a new tab

Tags: excel, vba

I have a worksheet ("Analysis") with a dropdown validation list that has 5 options. The dropdown is in cell B6. I want to iterate through the 5 options in this dropdown, which produce different summary results contained in the range B10:N25, and then copy the values into a new worksheet ("Output"). I would like the summary results for each of these 5 iterations in the "Output" sheet, so need the code to update the destination cell in the Output sheet with each loop so it doesn't paste over the same area. Thank you!

I've tried a couple VBA options, but those were written for single lines of data or for creating new tabs for each iteration.

```
Sub Iteration_Loop()
'
' Iteration_Loop Macro
' Loops through alternatives
'

' create variables
    Dim input As Range
    Dim c As Range

    Set input = Evaluate(Sheets("Analysis").Range("B6").Validation.Formula1)
    For Each c In input
    Calculate
    Sheets("Analysis").Range("B10:N25").Copy
    Sheets("Output Sheet").Range("C5").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats
    'Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats, Operation:=
    '    xlNone , SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False

    Next c

End Sub
```

I think this does the iteration, but just copies over the same range in Output.

Answer (score 1):

though could not understand question clearly, it is assumed that destination cells change with the iteration (otherwise it is bound to overlap previously pasted area). I used it to be copied one below other with 20 rows block as shown

[image: shown]. 
`Input` is a keyword in VBA and could not be used as variable.

```
Sub Iteration_Loop()
Dim Rng As Range
Dim c As Range
Dim DestRow As Long

     'Set Rng to the list of values in the validation list
Set Rng = Sheets("Analysis").Range(Sheets("Analysis").Range("B6").Validation.Formula1)
DestRow = 0

     For Each c In Rng.Cells
     Sheets("Analysis").Range("B6").Value = c.Value
     Application.Calculate
     Sheets("Analysis").Range("B10:N25").Copy
     Sheets("Output Sheet").Range("C" & DestRow + 5).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats
     DestRow = DestRow + 20
     Next c

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution including comments in the code:

```
Sub t()

    'Input will give you an error
    Set Input_Analysis = Evaluate(Sheets("Analysis").Range("B6").Validation.Formula1)
    For Each Value In Input_Analysis
        'Calculate -> you can use Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic, you should set it to xlManual first if you want to stop it, default - auto
        Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
        '+ 2 since you want to paste it at least (1) row beneath the last one
        Last_Filled_Row = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Output Sheet").Range("C104764").End(xlUp).Row + 2
        'assuming you at least want to start pasting as of row 15
        If Last_Filled_Row < 15 Then
            Last_Filled_Row = 15
        End If

        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Analysis").Range("B10:N25").Copy
        'use the row as retrieved above
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Output Sheet").Range("C" & Last_Filled_Row).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats
    Next Value

End Sub
```